# NodeJS and AngularJS: Download file $http.get() and save to folder

Tags: angularjs, node.js, electron, fs, angularjs-http

I'm developing an **Electron** app using **NodeJS and AngularJS** to download mp3 files from a web service and save them to a specific folder.
To accomplish this, i'm using AngularJS $http.get() to download the files and Node File System to save the downloaded data to a folder.

My problem at the moment is that i'm unable to save the file correctly. The data is downloaded and a file is created, but it seems corrupted. In other words the MP3 doesn't work.

Here's a sample code of what i'm doing:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");

var resquest = $http.get(url, config).then(function(response)
{
    var downloadFolder = path.join(app.getAppPath(), '../../downloads/test.mp3');

    var filestream = fs.writeFile(downloadFolder, response.data, 'binary');
});
```

**UPDATE: Tested the following approach based on @hame-dhib suggestion:**

```
var request = $http({
    method:'GET',
    responseType: 'blob', //<---
    url:'http://api/',
    headers:
    {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg', //<---
        'Authorization': data.token
    }
}).then(function successCallback(response)
{
    var downloadFolder = path.join(app.getAppPath(), '../../downloads/test.mp3');

    var filestream = fs.writeFile(downloadFolder, response.data, 'binary');

}, function errorCallback(response)
{
    console.log(response);
});
```

The problem still persists.

Comment: It's unclear what's going on there. How comes that AngularJS (client side) calls Node fs (server side)? Is it Electron app? The question should state the problem clearly. As for 'still persists', please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @estus you are right. I forgot to mention its an Electron app. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

You should define responseType as blob :

```
$http({
  method:'POST',
  responseType: 'blob', //<---
  url:'/api/lessons',
  data:{cards:lessonList},
  headers : {
    'Content-type' : 'audio/mpeg',
  }
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config){ ..
```